# Upgrade C# windows form project from VS2005 to VS2008, can't debug anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a C# windows form application (Actually it is a IE toolbar application), I have been working with it in VS2005 for years and everything is fine. Recently, I upgrade my IDE to VS2008, and also import that project to VS2008, but after import, in VS2008 I can't start debugging any more, it always show: "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging"

While import, I kept the same .net framework as in VS2005, double checked the debug setting is same as vs2005. I can compile the project without any issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the windows event log - see if there are any errors being reported

Comment: Are you able to debug any project on your machine?

Comment: @Preet Sangha, thanks, just checked the event log, nothing there.

Comment: @Jay Riggs, thanks, I can debug the same project in VS2005, I tried to create a new windows form project and tried to debug it in vs2008, it works fine. But I did create an empty IE plug-in project, it failed to debug, seems related to the Add-in-express module. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Verify that .NET 3.0+ is installed
   on your machine.  (not likely to be
   your problem but just a simple
   'sanity check')
2. [Here's a thread](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=6242) describing the same
   problem that you're experiencing on
   an IE addin project.  The solution
   that worked was to add "about:blank"
   (or any URL) to the debugging
   command line arguments.

   Maybe the problem isn't due so
   much to the upgrade to VS2008, but to
   differences to how VS2005 and VS2008
   debug IE addins, or perhaps this is a
   setting you haven't migrated to
   VS2008.  It's worth a look though.

Comment: @Jay, I double checked, my computer does have .net framework 2.0SP2, 3.0SP2 and 3.5SP1 installed. also my application only use 2.0. 

Thanks for the link, I use add-in-express for ie too. I created an empty add-in-express for ie application, I can't debug that one either, so I guess it must be something wrong with the add-in-express module. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to add command line arguments, it does solve the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't starting with a new code directory ad you haven't already, try Build - > Clean, Build -> Rebuild. That sometimes cleans the gunk out. I always feel likes that's the visual studio equivalent of "reboot your computer" advice, but it's cliche because it often works.

I know Rebuild was at least originally supposed to be the same as Clean + Build, but sometimes need to do it anyway.

Comment: @Jim, thanks, I tried clean it but still have the same issue, I found it is related to add-in-express module.